# Elastic Search Docker Image License

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

What is the license of ElasticSearch docker images? It is said that binary distributions are Elastic Licensed. See [Elastic FAQ](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing) But what is the condition for docker images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch). So is the license constraint for 6.8.23  and 8.3.3  docker image are same and it is Elastic License? Or 8.3.3 is with the Elastic License and 6.8.23 with Apache 2.0.

If docker images are built with source code compiled then they should be Apache 2.0 licensed depending on the version. If they are built with the binary versions then any docker image is subject to the Elastic License I guess. Any clarifications will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the docker files you can see that they are built with binaries, specifically the tar.gz, and not from source

https://github.com/elastic/dockerfiles also mentions;

> This software is governed by their applicable licenses, and includes the full set of free features.

to your point, yes, it will depend on what version you are running as to what license applies

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Walkom mentioned the docker image at the Docker hub is created from the tar.gz. But I checked the inside of provided by the Elastic. The license file for the elastic itself is Apache 2.0. I used the image docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.23.

[image]

But when I check the non oss version it is not Apache, it is ELv1 probably. So I deduce that this oss docker image can be used with the Apache 2.0 license.